# Issue calculating sleep time with moment.js and react native.

Tags: react-native, momentjs, datetimepicker

[Detailed screenshot of issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMttj.jpg)

I'm trying to calculate sleep time in react native using moment.js and this [datetime picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker). When I try it, the result is always 0 which is not correct.

This is the format that I'm using from moment.js: moment.duration(moment(this.selectedEndDateTime).diff(moment(this.selectedStartDateTime))).asHours().

[Snack link with working code:](https://snack.expo.io/SJnAwnROQ)

```
export default class DateTimePickerTester extends Component {

state = {
    startDateTimePickerVisible: false,
    endDateTimePickerVisible: false,
    selectedStartDateTime: moment().format('ddd MMM D YYYY 12:00 AM').toUpperCase(),
    selectedEndDateTime: moment().format('ddd MMM D YYYY 8:00 AM').toUpperCase(),
  };

  showStartDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ startDateTimePickerVisible: true });
  showEndDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ endDateTimePickerVisible: true });

  hideStartDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ startDateTimePickerVisible: false });
  hideEndDateTimePicker = () => this.setState({ endDateTimePickerVisible: false });

  handleStartDateTimePicked = (datetime) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedStartDateTime: moment(datetime).format('ddd MMM D YYYY h:mm a').toUpperCase()
      })
    this.hideStartDateTimePicker();
  };

  handleEndDateTimePicked = (datetime) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedEndDateTime: moment(datetime).format('ddd MMM D YYYY h:mm a').toUpperCase()
      })
    this.hideEndDateTimePicker();
    this.displaySleepDuration()
  };

  displaySleepDuration = (datetime) => {
    this.setState({
      sleepDuration: moment.duration(moment(this.selectedEndDateTime).diff(moment(this.selectedStartDateTime))).asHours()
    })
  }

  render () {
    console.log( this.state.sleepDuration )
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 50 }}>

        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 10 }}>
           Time Slept: {this.state.sleepDuration}
        </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showStartDateTimePicker}>
          <Text>
            In Bed: {this.state.selectedStartDateTime}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showEndDateTimePicker}>
          <Text>
            Awake: {this.state.selectedEndDateTime}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <DateTimePicker
          mode='datetime'
          isVisible={this.state.startDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleStartDateTimePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideStartDateTimePicker}
        />

        <DateTimePicker
          mode='datetime'
          isVisible={this.state.endDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleEndDateTimePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideEndDateTimePicker}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Issue numbers refer to the ones assigned in the provided screenshot.*

#### Issue 1

Your use of `moment.duration()` and `moment.diff()` are correct, however, you are referencing undefined objects: you must reference the state properties:

```
this.setState({
  sleepDuration: moment.duration(  
    moment(this.state.selectedEndDateTime).diff(         // instead of this.selectedEndDateTime
    moment(this.state.selectedStartDateTime))).asHours() // instead of this.selectedStartDateTime
})
```

#### Issue 2

You are trying to format moment objects with actual values, which is invalid. Please refer to the [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) documentation.

Instead, you should first manipulate the moment object before formatting it, like this:

```
selectedStartDateTime: moment().hours(0).minutes(0).format('ddd MMM D YYYY h:mm a').toUpperCase(),
selectedEndDateTime: moment().hours(8).minutes(0).format('ddd MMM D YYYY h:mm a').toUpperCase()
```

*Note the correct formatting string and that 12 AM is 0 hours*.

#### Issue 3

You are not setting the initial time to the datepickers. The [library props documentation](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker#available-props) says that you can pass a `date` prop to set the initial value:

```
 <DateTimePicker
   mode='datetime'
   datetime='12:00'
   isVisible={this.state.startDateTimePickerVisible}
   onConfirm={this.handleStartDateTimePicked}
   onCancel={this.hideStartDateTimePicker}
   date={moment().hours(0).minutes(0).toDate()}
 />

 <DateTimePicker
   mode='datetime'
   isVisible={this.state.endDateTimePickerVisible}
   onConfirm={this.handleEndDateTimePicked}
   onCancel={this.hideEndDateTimePicker}
   date={moment().hours(8).minutes(0).toDate()}
 />
```

Comment: @ericm21 friendly reminder: on your next questions on Stackoverflow be careful to limit them to *one issue each*, otherwise they could be flagged for being too broad. Should you have more issues with one piece of code, you could split them into separate questions :)

You could also have a look at the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more details.